# How to delete extra plots on a AxesSubplot object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a AxesSubplot object `ax1` from this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
```

I plot multiple times on this `ax1` to see how `alpha` values will set the plots' appearance:

```
first = ax1.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.3)
second = ax1.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.6)
third = ax1.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.9)
```

But these three plots overlap each other:

[image]

How can I erase the former histogram , then only show one plot each time? And by the way, what does the alpha arg do?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want,then try this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
```

Output
[image]

```
first = ax1.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.3)
second = ax2.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.6)
third = ax3.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.9)

plt.show()
```